# How to return array of images and its text content in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am really new with Javascript and I need help on how to display an array of book cover thumbnails with their titles and prices using a table in Javascript. This is what I have so far.

```
var bookImages = new Array ('images/animals-116x150.jpg', 'images/dog-loves-counting-125x150.jpg', ...);

var bookTitle = new Array ('Animals And Their Families', 'Dog Loves Counting', ...);

var bookDescr = new Array ('...','....');

var authors = new Array ('By Barbara Nascimbeni', 'By Louise Yates', ...);

var coverPrice = new Array ('Hardcover, <b>Price: $5.99 CDN</b></style>; 'Hardcover, <b>Price: $5.99 CDN</b>', ...);

var books = document.getElementById("bookSales");

var a;

var bookContent = '<table>';  *this  part contains open table tag, just not showing for some reason*

for (a = 0; a < bookImages.length; a++) {

    bookContent += "<tr><td><img src='" + bookImages[a] + "</td>";  
    bookContent += "<td>" + "<b>" + bookTitle[a] + "</b>" + "<br>" + bookDescr[a] + "<br>" + authors[a] + "<br>" + coverPrice[a] + 
    "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>" + "</td></tr>"; 
}

bookContent += "</table>"; *this contains end table tag*

books.innerHTML = bookContent;
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What isn't functioning as intended and have you checked the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only one array that will contain object. Each object will represent a book an all its properties. You can then simply call `book.description` to get the description of a book while iterating your array

```js
let books = [{
  image: 'image/A.png',
  title: 'Mysterious Book',
  description: 'foo..faa.',
  authors: ['John McFee', 'Jack McGordon'],
  coverPrice: 5.99
}, {
  image: 'image/B.png',
  title: 'What a Book',
  description: 'descriptio is life',
  authors: ['Gipsy Guy'],
  coverPrice: 10.95
}];
let bookSales = document.getElementById('bookSales');
let list = "";
books.forEach(book => {
  list += "<tr>";
  list += "<td><img src='" + book.image + "'></td>";
  list += "<td>" + "<b>" + book.title + "</b>" + "<br>" + book.description + "<br>" +     book.authors.join(',') + "<br>" + book.coverPrice + "</td>";
  list += "</tr>";

});
bookSales.innerHTML += list;
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="bookSales">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way of using condensed array to make this table since it is required in my class, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Joan There are no difference between condensed arrays and literal arrays

Comment: ok great, is there a way of making the images a thumbnail for this code?

Comment: @Joan You should set correct path for the image and they will appear

Comment: I have added the url for the images, however, I am not sure where to add the href so I can click on the image to show a bigger picture of the book.

Comment: @Joan This is another problem. Find yourself a solution and if you can't, come back on SO with another question